# Expect return of a standard Brownian motion

Tags: expected-value, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I'm working on the problem for a university project, I struggling for several days, I would post the same question with different coefficients from the problem I currently working on, so please show me the process to solve it and then I would learn by myself, your help is really important to me, please!

The questions are below:

Suppose $(W_t)$ is a standard Brownian motion, $t > 0$. Let $H$ be the first time the process $$X_t = W_t^2 + 2t$$ hits the value $a > 0$, what is $\mathbb E[H]$?

I tried to do it using the optional stopping theorem, but I got stuck, please help me if you know how to do it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are on the right path with optional stopping. Which martingale would you like to apply it to?